# Comparing two elements of a categorical variable according to their ordered categorization

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

In Python, I create a categorical variable like this:

```
x = pd.Categorical(["Hi", "Lo", "Med", "Zer", "Lo", "Zer", "Lo", "Hi"], categories = ["Zer", "Lo", "Med", "Hi"], ordered=True)
```

I want to compare element 0 with element 1. In principle, "Hi" is greater than "Lo". Why do I get `False` when I type `x[0] > x[1]`?

How do I compare two elements of a categorical variable according to their ordered categorization?

Comment: You are stepping out of pandas' categories into raw values. The solution provider below is one way to handle the scalar comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you slice a single item, you're back to having a python string and lose all information on order:

```
type(x[0])
# str
```

To have a working comparison you need to remain as array:

```
x[[0]]>x[[1]]
# array([ True])
```

When using pandas/numpy you generally want to perform vectorial operations, i.e handle multiple items/comparisons at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare [`codes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.codes.html#pandas.Categorical.codes):

```py
x = pd.Categorical(
    ["Hi", "Lo", "Med", "Zer", "Lo", "Zer", "Lo", "Hi"],
    categories=["Zer", "Lo", "Med", "Hi"],
    ordered=True,
)

print(x.codes[0] > x.codes[1])
```

Prints:

```
True
```